# Distance between hazard functions?

Tags: distributions, survival, distance, hazard

Let $F$ and $G$ two cumulative distribution functions with support on $(0,\infty)$. I know of many distances between distributions: Total Variation, Wasserstein, Hellinger, Kullback Liebler (divergence), and etcetera.

However, I would like to measure the distance between their hazard functions
$h_F(t) = \dfrac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}$ and $h_G(t) = \dfrac{g(t)}{1-G(t)}$, where $f$ and $g$ are the corresponding probability density functions.

**Question**:  Are there any distances between the hazard functions $h_F$ and $h_G$?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for and why?  After all, the hazard function determines the cdf, so why won't any of these metrics for cdfs work for you?

Comment: @whuber Basically, some distances are based on the cdf, while others on the pdf. I was wondering if there are some others that are based on the hazard function as hazards can be of all kinds of shapes.

Comment: My point is that there is no distinction involved in your "based on concept" since $h$ and $F$ are just two different ways of denoting the same distribution.  It's like asking whether there are different ways you can weigh people depending on whether you call them by their last name or first name... .

Comment: @whuber I think there is a difference. Your example is valid, but entirely different and unrelated. For instance, the Wasserstein distance, based on the CDF, is not invariant under changes of variable, while the TV distance, based on the PDF is. That is one of the reasons why it makes sense to define different types of distances. My point is whether or not there is one based on the hazard.

Comment: I am just asking for clarification.  I don't know what you mean by "invariant under changes of variable," because when you transform a random variable, you usually change its CDF, too.  Mathematically, literally *any* distance you can define for two CDFs can be expressed as a distance between their hazard functions--that shouldn't be under discussion. You intimate now that you are looking for distances that might satisfy certain properties.  What would they be?

Comment: @whuber Cool, I know your usual tone where nothing makes except what you say. I take my leave out of here. Just to clarify, the W distance is not invariant under transformations, that is not under debate, it is a well known result. Adieu.

Comment: My "usual tone" is to help threads to be clear and unambiguous, as explained in our [help].  It is too confusing for everyone when there are multiple different interpretations of an attempted question.  I wish we could guess correctly what you are looking for, but we do need your help.